Как настроить поиск в Joomla mod_djс2search без ошибок?
Всем добрый день! Есть сайт на Joomla 3.9.2, для каталога используется DJCatalog2, в нем есть модуль поиска, но он работает некорректно. Если я на сайте нахожусь в категории и кликаю на поиск, то все хорошо, но если я а главной, то после клика на поиск пропадает шапка сайта. Подскажите, что и где нужно сделать, что всё работала корректно, я совсем не понимаю куда копать
